# Trouble understanding CONNECTIVITY_ACTION extras

Tags: android

To be notified of network connections and disconnects, and to then know if my application can connect to the internet, I register a `ConnectionManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` receiver. At present, I check if the phone has an active network connection like so:

```
if (intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false)) {
    // no connection!
} else {
    NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
    if (activeNetInfo != null && activeNetInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        // active connection!
    } else {
        // no connection!
    } 
}
```

However, I think I'm doing this wrong because my app can sometimes misreport the phone's connectivity status. Reading the documentation for `EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO`, it seems to indicate that if the value returned for this extra is null, then there is no connection: "...if the connectivity manager is attempting to connect (or has already connected) to another network, the NetworkInfo for the new network is also passed as an extra" (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION).

However in instances where my app misreports connectivity, just prior to receiving the `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` broadcast, `getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo()` returns a `NetworkInfo` object whose `isConnectedOrConnecting()` check returns true. So the phone appears to be connected, but the `NetworkInfo` returned via the `CONNECTIVITY_BROADCAST` is null.

What am I doing wrong in my `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` receiver code? Should I not check the value of `EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO)`? Can I simply rely on `EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY`?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO` is deprecated use  getActiveNetworkInfo() or getAllNetworkInfo(). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong, but the only reliable value coming from isConnectedOrConnecting is false.

Even when the method returns true, you're not guaranteed that you'll be able to connect to the network.

When Android reports that you in fact  have an active connection, you'll need to implement some kind of retry mechanism in case the connection doesn't seem to workable.

This can be the case for example when connecting to a corporate WIFI network, where all requests end up redirecting to the corporate login page. Android tells you that you have an active network, but your queries will obviously fail.

But even with a direct network connection, relying on it to return true is never a good idea without have some kind of retry mechanism in place for when things go wrong.

On the other hand, when the method returns false, you're guaranteed not to have a network connection.

Comment: If I should only trust the return from isConnectedOrConnecting(), then if in my CONNECTIVITY_ACTION receiver, if the EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO is null, should I assume that there is an active network connection?

Comment: You should only trust it when !activeNetInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() or when activeNetInfo==null. 
At that point you are 100% sure there is no network connectivity. If it returns true, you know a connection is being established, however, in order to ensure that there is actual network connectivity to some specific host, you'll need to implement a check yourself, or implement a retry algorithm for your network calls.

Comment: I understand your point, but I think that in my specific case, my "is disconnected" check is evaluating to true because I misunderstood the broadcast's documentation: "For a loss of connectivity, if the connectivity manager is attempting to connect (or has already connected) to another network, the NetworkInfo for the new network is also passed as an extra." which would seem to indicate that if the phone did not lose a connection, but instead gained it, that this extra would not be sent.